# Closed form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^n(4n-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Closed form of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^n(4n-1)}$$
the Wolfram gave  me the answer below, but I ask if there is a clear value of this sum
[image]

Comment: $\frac{\coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)-\cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt[4]{2}}-1$

Comment: Or, if it is more useful $-1+\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\exp (s)}{2 e^{4 s}-1} \, ds$

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo, thanks, but how did you get it?

Comment: separate the $n=0$ contribution. Then, in the summation from $1$ to $\infty$ use $\frac{1}{4n-1}=\int_0^\infty ds\ e^{-s (4n-1)}$ and exchange integral and summation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n(4n-1)}&=-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^1 x^{4n-2}\,dx\\\\
&=-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{(x^4/2)^n}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-1+\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2-x^4}\,dx\\\\
&=-1+\frac{\text{atanh}\left(2^{-1/4}\right)-\text{atan}\left(2^{-1/4}\right)}{2^{5/4}}\\\\
&\approx -0.779247 
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think the answer is $-0.779247$

Comment: @E.H.E Yes it is.  Edited!  And much appreciative of your catching the typo.  +1

Comment: very nice, thanks(+1)

Comment: You're welcome EHE!  My pleasure.  - Mark

Answer (score 5):

Consider

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4 n}}{4 n+3} $$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left [x^3 f(x) \right ] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{4 n+2}  = \frac{x^2}{1-x^4}$$

Integrate both sides...

$$x^3 f(x) = \frac14 \log{\left (\frac{1+x}{1-x} \right )} - \frac12 \arctan{x} + C $$

where $C=0$ by considering $x=0$.   The series is equal to

$$f(2^{-1/4}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{2^n} \frac1{4 n+3} = 2^{3/4} \left [\frac14 \log{\left (\frac{1+2^{-1/4}}{1-2^{-1/4}} \right )} - \frac12 \arctan{2^{-1/4}} \right ]$$

The relation to your series is

$$-1 + \frac12 f(2^{-1/4}) \approx -0.779247$$